# Xamarin Forms iOS custom UITableViewCell dynamic height

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create custom UITableViewCell for Xamarin Forms that will automatically adjust it's height according to the text it contains.

I have found solutions that are made through Designer, but I need to do this in code.

This is what I have now after analyzing the Designer solutions, but it does not work:

```
public class FormLabelCellView : UITableViewCell, INativeElementView
{
    public UILabel Label { get; private set; }
    public FormLabelCell Cell { get; set; }
    public Element Element => Cell;

    public FormLabelCellView(FormLabelCell cell) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cell.GetType().FullName)
    {
        Cell = cell;
        // in the custom ContentView solution I can't set the cell to expand and contract according to the text it contains
        Label = new UILabel();

        Label.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        Label.SetContentCompressionResistancePriority(751, UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical);
        Label.SetContentHuggingPriority(251, UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical);

        this.ContentView.AddSubview(Label);

        this.ContentView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(Label, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0));
        this.ContentView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(Label, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, 0));
        this.ContentView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(Label, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 0));
        this.ContentView.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(Label, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this.ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));
    }
}
```

This is the result (the row height is probably DefaultRowHeight of 44):

[image: custom ContentView solution]

Before anyone asks about *RowHeight* and *EstimatedRowHeight*. Yes I have set **RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;** and **EstimatedRowHeight = 24;** in my custom ListViewRenderer.

I can also verify that it works when I modify my custom UITableViewCell to this:

```
public class FormLabelCellView : UITableViewCell, INativeElementView
{
    public UILabel Label { get; private set; }
    public FormLabelCell Cell { get; set; }
    public Element Element => Cell;

    public FormLabelCellView(FormLabelCell cell) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cell.GetType().FullName)
    {
        Cell = cell;
        // this solution works, but I can't remove the margins / padding and set background color
        Label = this.TextLabel;
    }
}
```

Then the result looks like this:

[image: using TextLabel]

I think I'm not creating the constraints correctly. Can someone help me?

Edit: After trying to create custom UITableViewSource for testing purposes I have found that the problem is in the Xamarin implementation of **ListViewDataSource** and **UnevenListViewDataSource**. This is unfortunate because these classes are internal so I can't extend them and override the GetHeightForRow function.

Comment: MayBe it is problem with VisualStudio or symulator. I have problem with custom renderer on iOS. It doesn't work until I restart VS and simulator.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm struggling with this for a long time. I have tried many things, but nothing gives me the result I want. I think that I must be doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question. The problem is in the Xamarin implementation of internal classes **ListViewDataSource** and **UnevenListViewDataSource**. Because we can't extend these classes there are two possible solutions for dynamic row height in ListView.

1. Create own implementation of **UITableViewSource**.
2. Use **ViewCell** to create your custom cell.

I have used the second option, because I'm doing multi-platform application and I don't want to create complicated implementation of **UITableViewSource**.

So this is example implementation of custom ViewCell:

```
public class CustomLabelCell : ViewCell
{
    private Label label;

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(CustomLabelCell), null);

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // disable public set on View property
    public new View View
    {
        get { return base.View; }
        private set { base.View = value; }
    }

    public CustomLabelCell()
    {
        this.label = new Label()
        {
            Text = this.Text
        };
        ContentView frame = new ContentView()
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(4.0),
            Content = label
        };
        this.View = frame;
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == TextProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            this.label.Text = this.Text;
            ForceUpdateSize();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how you would use it in ListView:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement)
{
    HasUnevenRows = true,
    ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<TestObj> { new TestObj("one - example text that will reach s e c o n d row"), new TestObj("two"), new TestObj("three - longer example text with more words for third row that will span across three rows"), new TestObj("four"), new TestObj("five") },
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomLabelCell))
};
listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(CustomLabelCell.TextProperty, "Name");
```

For completeness this is implementation of TestObj:

```
public class TestObj : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    public TestObj(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

As you see there is no necessity to create custom renderers and custom cells in platform specific code.

Answer (score 1):

In my test, If I set `RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;` and `EstimatedRowHeight = 24;` in the listViewRenderer, I will get the same effect as you show: the TableView seems having an equal row height.

But when I try to use another way: using override method in the tableView's source like:

```
public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    return UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
}

public override nfloat EstimatedHeight(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    return 24;
}
```

It works fine(The cell will auto resize its row height in the run time).

Moreover I really recommend you to use this method to construct your Cell:

```
public MyListViewCell(NSString cellId) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
{
     //add your controls in the cell's ContentView
}
```

Then we can use it in the Source like:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    MyListViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("Cell") as MyListViewCell;

    if (cell == null)
    {
        cell = new MyListViewCell(new NSString("Cell"));
    }

    //Update your data

    return Cell;
}
```

Comment: I didn't mention this, but I'm not using custom UITableViewSource. I'm using the default data source that xamarin creates when you populate ItemsSource property in ListView. I wanted only to extend the default ListView, not to recreate all the functionality that is already there. But I have tried your suggestion and created very basic custom UITableViewSource and it works. Also I didn't have to override the GetHeightForRow and EstimatedHeight for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SetUpCell(string ParticipantName)
        {
            ParticipantNameLabel.Text = ParticipantName;
        }

public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("PeopleCell", indexPath) as PeopleCell;

            if (cell == null)
            {
                cell = new PeopleCell(new NSString("PeopleCell"));
            }
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
            cell.SetUpCell(ListPeople[indexPath.Row]);

            return cell;
        }
```

When I call `cell.SetUpCell()` I am getting a null reference on the `ParticipantNameLabel` which I instantiate inside of the constructor that you demonstrated above.

```
public MyListViewCell(NSString cellId) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
{
     //add your controls in the cell's ContentView
}
```

If i place the instantiation within constructor below, I don't get this null reference.

```
public PeopleCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you should post your implementation of **PeopleCell** class, so we can see where the problem could be. I have left this approach of creating custom _UITableViewCell_ and custom _UITableViewSource_ and instead I have used ViewCell to create my custom cell.